# При первом посещении сайта с поисковика редирект на рекламный

Tags: modx, redirect

Есть сайт организации, ранжирующийся в Google и Yandex. При самом первом (на данном устройстве) переходе с этих поисковых систем, открывается:
https://ibb.co/qJWXDbH

Где нужно покопаться для решения?

Comment: Сайт заражен вирусом, код либо в js файле, либо в шапке шаблона, либо в php в виде какого-нибудь eval. Просите хостера проверить сайт на вирусы, они должны(читай обязаны) проверить и прислать отчет. Можете сами запустить Айболита или Ревизиум.

Answer (score 0):

Узнайте, может ли хостер проверить сам(некоторые предлагают такую услугу по умолчанию, у других платно), можете сами проверить, как уточнили ранее, либо даже скачать локально и проверить у себя.